# is there a MixRBG node with input for multiple maps?

Tags: texturing, materials

do you know any addon that has a MixRBG node with input for multiple maps?
one that has the mix setup for each input channel on the map?

Comment: Have you tried the *Combine RGB* node? Plug that into one of the *MixRGB*'s color sockets, and you can plug your RGB channels in separately. I assume that's what you want.

Comment: it's not that . I wanted to simplify the map tree by subtracting several Mixrgb nodes by just one mixrgb with several map entries. it's possible ?

Comment: I see. I'm not sure if there's an add-on for that, but you can try grouping your nodes together by selecting them and pressing Ctrl+G.

Comment: To mixRGB from multiple sources, you need multiple factors to mix (and some methods for mixRGB wouldn't make sense, or at least require disambiguation.)  If I want to mixRGB on mix mode from >2 inputs, I will usually sequentially do mixRGB/adds, with the first adding from black.